# k2 textbox contains a value

Tags: k2, k2-blackpearl

I am new to K2, I have textbox which got mapped to receive a value like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><results operation="invokeSync"> 
<resultStatus>OK</resultStatus> 
<output>  
<content>Error</content> 
</output>
</results>
```

I just want to check if it contains "Error" value.
I treid

if control contains specific value (If control contains Error(specific value))

if control contains a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the rules.

### 1.You have a rule called **if a control contains a value**, by using this we can check whether the text-box is having any value.

### 2. You have another rule saying **If a control contains a specific value**, by using this rule you can check whether your text-box contain a specific value or not.

You can choose this rule based on where you place your text-box like you may place your text-box on form level or you may place the text-box on view level.

Thank You